# Drupal static homepage not working

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

First off, I'm completely new to Drupal, so I could be making a ridiculously simple mistake...

I'm using Drupal 7.9, and trying to use an HTML homepage that I've already created, that does not follow the Theme...

I've tried using the page-front.tpl.php file, but it is completely ignored.  I then found that in Drupal 7 I should be using page--front.tpl.php, but that is ignored as well.

I've looked through many different tutorial and FAQs, but to no avail.  Can someone possibly point out what I'm doing wrong?  I've even added some test text to the page.tpl.php file, just to make sure that it's loading that one instead; which it is.  Is there some setting that I'm missing that tells Drupal to use the page--front.tpl.php file?

Here's the server setup...
Windows Server 8;
IIS 7;
MySQL 5
PHP 5

I know, we should be using Linux and Apache...  I'm still working on getting our Windows happy VP to let me make the switch...:)

Thanks for any help, I'm at a loss here...

--Charles

Comment: Did you create this home page in Drupal or is it a static page?

Comment: The current page is written in HTML5.  I was going to create a WordPress CMS site; but, decided to switch to Drupal.  I'd like to just use that HTML5 page, but am not opposed to converting it to a Drupal page.  The only issue is that the homepage will not be the same design as the sub-pages...

Comment: Drupal can accommodate a different design for the front page.  IF you use Panels module, you could change it for every page or page type you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal manages all pages dynamically and stores content in the database.  You will be able to designate a specific page as your home page and render it differently than other pages if you wish.  Drupal is extremely flexible and capable of almost anything by using the many expansion modules that are available for it.  Having said that, you should also know that there is a 'learning curve' to Drupal so don't expect good results right off the bat.  If this is a one-off project, you may want to look at other alternatives as well.

Comment: Thanks...  I'll look into the database and see what I can find in there.  I understand the learning curve, I just am not having any luck with the homepage...:)  This is actually the beginnings of a whole website rebuild.  I've been tasked with rebuilding everything, by next Fall, based on images provided by our PR department... :)  fun...:)

Comment: If you know your way a bit around website design, HTML, CSS, PHP, maybe some javaScript, Drupal is a great tool.  Don't jump in to the site first, spend some time at nodeone.se , lullabot.com, mustardseedmedia.com, or Lynda.com all of whom have great videos to learn Drupal basics.  There are excellent books on Drupal.  I recommend the fat ones (more stuff in them) like the Definitive Guide to Drupal.  Also Drupal Building Blocks is a must. Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointers.  I'll definitely look around those sites...  And, I've got a couple or books that I've requested through my employer...:)  Again, thanks for the pointers and assist.